# Accesing Hybris backoffice causes a freeze in the system for several minutes

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I keep getting this exception every other time I try to load the backoffice:

```
WARN  [hybrisHTTP16] [Transaction] Removal of file: C:\<...long path...>\8797073866782.xml has failed.
...
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\<...long path...>\8797073866782.xml: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

It freezes the loading of backoffice for several minutes. I gues it continuous trying to remove this file until it succedes. It is very annoying. And I dont know what process is blocking it. I ried to close my Intelij, i seem to work several times, but the last time I had the Problem with no Intelij running. Any gueses what processes can block the file and how to fix it?

I am on a Windows machine with hybris 1808.

Stack trace looks like:

```
WARN  [hybrisHTTP16] [Transaction] Removal of file: C:\Projects\fujitsu\hybris\data\media\sys_master\backofficeconfiguration\h51\h1a\8797073866782.xml has failed.
de.hybris.platform.media.exceptions.MediaRemovalException: Removal of file: C:\Projects\fujitsu\hybris\data\media\sys_master\backofficeconfiguration\h51\h1a\8797073866782.xml has failed.
        at de.hybris.platform.media.storage.impl.LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.delete(LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.java:206) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.media.MediaManager.deleteMedia(MediaManager.java:299) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.media.MediaDataStoreCommand$2.execute(MediaDataStoreCommand.java:250) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction.executeTxAwareInternal(Transaction.java:1674) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction.executeAllDelayedTransactionExecutions(Transaction.java:1686) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction.notifyCommit(Transaction.java:972) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction.clearTxBoundConnectionAndNotify(Transaction.java:894) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction.commitConnectionAndClearAndUnsetAsCurrent(Transaction.java:703) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction.commit(Transaction.java:679) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.backoffice.config.impl.DefaultMediaCockpitConfigurationPersistenceStrategy$3.executeWithoutResult(DefaultMediaCockpitConfigurationPersistenceStrategy.java:128) ~[classes/:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionExecutionBody.execute(SessionExecutionBody.java:28) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        ...
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.40]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.40]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_231]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.40]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Projects\fujitsu\hybris\data\media\sys_master\backofficeconfiguration\h51\h1a\8797073866782.xml: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at de.hybris.platform.media.storage.impl.LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.delete(LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.java:201) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        ... 160 more
WARN  [hybrisHTTP16] [Transaction] Removal of file: C:\Projects\fujitsu\hybris\data\media\sys_master\backofficeconfiguration\h51\h1a\8797073866782.xml has failed.
de.hybris.platform.media.exceptions.MediaRemovalException: Removal of file: C:\Projects\fujitsu\hybris\data\media\sys_master\backofficeconfiguration\h51\h1a\8797073866782.xml has failed.
        at de.hybris.platform.media.storage.impl.LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.delete(LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.java:206) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at de.hybris.platform.jalo.media.MediaManager.deleteMedia(MediaManager.java:299) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        ...
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Projects\fujitsu\hybris\data\media\sys_master\backofficeconfiguration\h51\h1a\8797073866782.xml: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
        at de.hybris.platform.media.storage.impl.LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.delete(LocalFileMediaStorageStrategy.java:201) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        ... 160 more
```

cmd > tasklist

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0          8 K
System                           4 Services                   0      1,628 K
Registry                        96 Services                   0     38,468 K
smss.exe                       396 Services                   0        596 K
csrss.exe                      560 Services                   0      3,984 K
wininit.exe                    644 Services                   0      4,472 K
csrss.exe                      652 Console                    1      4,988 K
services.exe                   720 Services                   0      9,680 K
winlogon.exe                   748 Console                    1      9,636 K
lsass.exe                      796 Services                   0     17,760 K
svchost.exe                    924 Services                   0      2,716 K
fontdrvhost.exe                948 Services                   0      1,604 K
fontdrvhost.exe                956 Console                    1      6,600 K
svchost.exe                    964 Services                   0     29,312 K
WUDFHost.exe                  1012 Services                   0      9,140 K
svchost.exe                    564 Services                   0     14,284 K
svchost.exe                    940 Services                   0      6,228 K
dwm.exe                       1124 Console                    1     51,896 K
svchost.exe                   1276 Services                   0      4,496 K
svchost.exe                   1308 Services                   0      8,296 K
svchost.exe                   1316 Services                   0     10,044 K
svchost.exe                   1432 Services                   0     12,360 K
svchost.exe                   1440 Services                   0     13,752 K
svchost.exe                   1496 Services                   0      7,556 K
svchost.exe                   1532 Services                   0      6,752 K
svchost.exe                   1584 Services                   0      4,316 K
svchost.exe                   1600 Services                   0      9,272 K
svchost.exe                   1648 Services                   0      5,872 K
svchost.exe                   1704 Services                   0      6,088 K
svchost.exe                   1716 Services                   0      5,196 K
svchost.exe                   1820 Services                   0      5,912 K
svchost.exe                   1916 Services                   0      8,128 K
svchost.exe                   2056 Services                   0     12,916 K
svchost.exe                   2076 Services                   0     10,184 K
svchost.exe                   2152 Services                   0      5,572 K
svchost.exe                   2160 Services                   0     11,740 K
svchost.exe                   2184 Services                   0      4,316 K
Memory Compression            2272 Services                   0    429,764 K
svchost.exe                   2320 Services                   0      7,896 K
igfxCUIService.exe            2352 Services                   0      6,552 K
svchost.exe                   2360 Services                   0      7,064 K
svchost.exe                   2452 Services                   0      5,744 K
svchost.exe                   2468 Services                   0      6,576 K
svchost.exe                   2564 Services                   0      8,192 K
svchost.exe                   2648 Services                   0     11,556 K
svchost.exe                   2712 Services                   0      5,032 K
svchost.exe                   2720 Services                   0      7,528 K
audiodg.exe                   2816 Services                   0     16,316 K
svchost.exe                   2824 Services                   0     15,344 K
svchost.exe                   2856 Services                   0     12,212 K
svchost.exe                   2008 Services                   0      6,660 K
svchost.exe                   3128 Services                   0      7,760 K
svchost.exe                   3156 Services                   0     19,224 K
svchost.exe                   3276 Services                   0     15,228 K
sihost.exe                    3300 Console                    1     24,756 K
svchost.exe                   3320 Console                    1     25,308 K
PresentationFontCache.exe     3384 Services                   0     12,388 K
svchost.exe                   3452 Console                    1     30,576 K
svchost.exe                   3460 Services                   0     11,328 K
svchost.exe                   3468 Services                   0     14,228 K
taskhostw.exe                 3592 Console                    1     15,168 K
spoolsv.exe                   3668 Services                   0      9,220 K
WmiPrvSE.exe                  3720 Services                   0     18,576 K
svchost.exe                   3792 Services                   0     10,676 K
svchost.exe                   3916 Services                   0      5,728 K
svchost.exe                   4008 Services                   0      5,956 K
wlanext.exe                   4084 Services                   0      9,940 K
conhost.exe                   2140 Services                   0      3,676 K
ctfmon.exe                    3240 Console                    1     16,260 K
igfxEM.exe                    3992 Console                    1     27,948 K
svchost.exe                   4132 Services                   0     12,288 K
svchost.exe                   4200 Services                   0      7,264 K
svchost.exe                   4412 Services                   0     10,032 K
HidMonitorSvc.exe             4496 Services                   0      4,136 K
armsvc.exe                    4508 Services                   0     14,272 K
mDNSResponder.exe             4532 Services                   0      4,864 K
OfficeClickToRun.exe          4540 Services                   0     46,084 K
svchost.exe                   4592 Services                   0     45,636 K
IntelCpHDCPSvc.exe            4616 Services                   0      5,264 K
svchost.exe                   4624 Services                   0     24,488 K
svchost.exe                   4656 Services                   0     43,984 K
EvtEng.exe                    4724 Services                   0     12,244 K
ibtsiva.exe                   4756 Services                   0      3,600 K
openvpnserv.exe               4784 Services                   0      4,240 K
mysqld.exe                    4820 Services                   0     92,216 K
svchost.exe                   4836 Services                   0      4,328 K
pdf24.exe                     4844 Services                   0      6,364 K
RegSrvc.exe                   4868 Services                   0      7,236 K
svchost.exe                   4884 Services                   0      5,904 K
valWBFPolicyService.exe       4948 Services                   0      5,608 K
WirelessKB850Notification     4956 Services                   0      4,460 K
ZeroConfigService.exe         4968 Services                   0     13,876 K
svchost.exe                   4980 Services                   0     19,284 K
MsMpEng.exe                   4988 Services                   0    167,012 K
svchost.exe                   5084 Services                   0      4,020 K
svchost.exe                   5132 Services                   0      3,676 K
svchost.exe                   5248 Services                   0     10,016 K
IntelCpHeciSvc.exe            5348 Services                   0      4,908 K
Apoint.exe                    5460 Console                    1     11,340 K
svchost.exe                   5488 Services                   0      5,388 K
unsecapp.exe                  5676 Services                   0      6,032 K
WmiPrvSE.exe                  5876 Services                   0     13,112 K
svchost.exe                   6036 Services                   0      5,716 K
svchost.exe                   5936 Services                   0      4,228 K
explorer.exe                  6220 Console                    1    143,604 K
svchost.exe                   6828 Console                    1     20,460 K
ApMsgFwd.exe                  6860 Console                    1      4,924 K
hidfind.exe                   7008 Console                    1      3,688 K
ApntEx.exe                    7016 Console                    1      5,060 K
conhost.exe                   7052 Console                    1      5,340 K
svchost.exe                   6992 Console                    1     29,088 K
NisSrv.exe                    6836 Services                   0      8,716 K
StartMenuExperienceHost.e     7588 Console                    1     58,716 K
RuntimeBroker.exe             7860 Console                    1     21,232 K
SearchUI.exe                  8036 Console                    1     68,996 K
RuntimeBroker.exe             8164 Console                    1     13,948 K
dllhost.exe                   3152 Services                   0      9,304 K
SkypeBackgroundHost.exe       7912 Console                    1      1,268 K
LockApp.exe                   8296 Console                    1     37,284 K
RuntimeBroker.exe             8372 Console                    1     25,516 K
svchost.exe                   8548 Services                   0      8,176 K
GoogleCrashHandler.exe        8920 Services                   0      1,112 K
GoogleCrashHandler64.exe      8936 Services                   0      1,036 K
RuntimeBroker.exe             9072 Console                    1     11,788 K
SecurityHealthSystray.exe     8528 Console                    1      6,460 K
SecurityHealthService.exe     8660 Services                   0     13,356 K
RAVCpl64.exe                  2992 Console                    1      9,836 K
svchost.exe                   4192 Services                   0      7,492 K
TCrdMain_Win8.exe             3016 Console                    1     16,464 K
TCrdKBB.exe                   7972 Console                    1      3,076 K
OneDrive.exe                  3584 Console                    1     43,568 K
openvpn-gui.exe               2068 Console                    1      6,152 K
MySQLNotifier.exe             9236 Console                    1     26,232 K
iCloudServices.exe            9328 Console                    1     40,216 K
APSDaemon.exe                 9428 Console                    1     14,824 K
ApplePhotoStreams.exe         9592 Console                    1     22,728 K
iCloudDrive.exe               9664 Console                    1     24,656 K
dts_apo_service.exe           9900 Services                   0     17,388 K
iCloudPhotos.exe             10088 Console                    1     35,720 K
svchost.exe                  10216 Services                   0     18,208 K
GoogleDriveFS.exe             9556 Console                    1     11,664 K
crashpad_handler.exe          2920 Console                    1      3,584 K
GoogleDriveFS.exe             6156 Console                    1     65,744 K
GoogleDriveFS.exe              568 Console                    1     47,768 K
GoogleDriveFS.exe             9832 Console                    1     70,020 K
pdf24.exe                    10916 Console                    1      7,152 K
chrome.exe                   11008 Console                    1    187,840 K
chrome.exe                   10324 Console                    1      4,684 K
chrome.exe                   11184 Console                    1      5,796 K
jusched.exe                  10380 Console                    1     15,312 K
chrome.exe                    6448 Console                    1    475,156 K
chrome.exe                    9864 Console                    1     49,596 K
chrome.exe                   11472 Console                    1     64,840 K
chrome.exe                   11492 Console                    1     25,560 K
cmd.exe                      11696 Console                    1      2,044 K
conhost.exe                  11716 Console                    1      5,312 K
AppleChromeDAV.exe           12060 Console                    1     26,372 K
svchost.exe                   8008 Services                   0      5,216 K
jhi_service.exe               5884 Services                   0      4,980 K
LMS.exe                      13280 Services                   0      8,608 K
SgrmBroker.exe                1332 Services                   0      5,740 K
sppsvc.exe                    6904 Services                   0      7,868 K
svchost.exe                   7132 Services                   0     15,376 K
svchost.exe                  10584 Services                   0      8,752 K
ApplicationFrameHost.exe      4588 Console                    1     30,728 K
WinStore.App.exe              4444 Console                    1        396 K
RuntimeBroker.exe             5444 Console                    1      6,588 K
YourPhone.exe                 2256 Console                    1      4,896 K
RuntimeBroker.exe             5004 Console                    1     13,480 K
ShellExperienceHost.exe      12628 Console                    1     95,200 K
RuntimeBroker.exe            13172 Console                    1     29,664 K
svchost.exe                   7768 Services                   0      6,572 K
svchost.exe                   7960 Services                   0      5,232 K
svchost.exe                  12788 Services                   0      6,700 K
SkypeApp.exe                   756 Console                    1      7,576 K
dasHost.exe                   5228 Services                   0      7,988 K
SettingSyncHost.exe           4908 Console                    1      3,380 K
RuntimeBroker.exe             8884 Console                    1      8,780 K
cmd.exe                       6132 Console                    1      5,572 K
conhost.exe                   9672 Console                    1     19,444 K
secd.exe                      2036 Console                    1     18,556 K
svchost.exe                  13068 Services                   0     15,792 K
WindowsInternal.Composabl     9164 Console                    1     33,944 K
svchost.exe                  12040 Services                   0     10,168 K
chrome.exe                   13072 Console                    1     45,684 K
svchost.exe                  14168 Services                   0     13,848 K
chrome.exe                    6364 Console                    1     12,824 K
svchost.exe                  13924 Services                   0     10,380 K
svchost.exe                   9456 Services                   0     17,028 K
dllhost.exe                   2384 Console                    1      8,312 K
isa.exe                       7304 Services                   0     16,924 K
FileCoAuth.exe               12820 Console                    1     10,328 K
Microsoft.Photos.exe         10724 Console                    1     53,084 K
RuntimeBroker.exe            13372 Console                    1     33,164 K
SystemSettings.exe            6576 Console                    1        232 K
chrome.exe                    8812 Console                    1     91,992 K
chrome.exe                    2584 Console                    1    128,312 K
chrome.exe                   12584 Console                    1     54,888 K
chrome.exe                   16760 Console                    1     43,432 K
svchost.exe                  11508 Services                   0      7,608 K
svchost.exe                  15144 Services                   0      7,368 K
notepad++.exe                 9604 Console                    1     16,276 K
chrome.exe                    8612 Console                    1     43,564 K
chrome.exe                   14328 Console                    1     61,648 K
chrome.exe                   16660 Console                    1    126,776 K
chrome.exe                    8708 Console                    1    193,152 K
svchost.exe                  12956 Services                   0      7,476 K
chrome.exe                    9340 Console                    1    134,404 K
Postman.exe                   7668 Console                    1     65,024 K
Postman.exe                   8392 Console                    1     24,156 K
SystemSettingsBroker.exe     13800 Console                    1     24,032 K
chrome.exe                   11800 Console                    1     45,160 K
chrome.exe                   14368 Console                    1     53,864 K
svchost.exe                  14396 Services                   0      7,520 K
svchost.exe                  15480 Services                   0      4,632 K
SearchIndexer.exe            16324 Services                   0     49,388 K
chrome.exe                    8364 Console                    1     90,416 K
chrome.exe                   14676 Console                    1    269,584 K
git-bash.exe                  8752 Console                    1      4,044 K
mintty.exe                    9296 Console                    1     15,096 K
conhost.exe                   6384 Console                    1      6,512 K
bash.exe                      2692 Console                    1      8,536 K
chrome.exe                   15264 Console                    1    115,808 K
MusNotifyIcon.exe             2296 Console                    1     11,848 K
HxOutlook.exe                14928 Console                    1        144 K
RuntimeBroker.exe            10616 Console                    1     20,784 K
HxTsr.exe                    16844 Console                    1     24,388 K
HxAccounts.exe               13512 Console                    1     49,916 K
PickerHost.exe                6772 Console                    1     31,544 K
AuthHost.exe                 17068 Console                    1    129,388 K
chrome.exe                   13360 Console                    1     45,216 K
chrome.exe                   13256 Console                    1     83,636 K
java.exe                     11544 Console                    1    340,784 K
chrome.exe                   16284 Console                    1    196,860 K
SearchProtocolHost.exe        4232 Services                   0     13,444 K
SearchFilterHost.exe           248 Services                   0      9,644 K
java.exe                      2368 Console                    1    614,936 K
chrome.exe                   15312 Console                    1     96,760 K
chrome.exe                   11036 Console                    1     73,804 K
chrome.exe                    9028 Console                    1     74,760 K
smartscreen.exe              14912 Console                    1     23,088 K
chrome.exe                   17968 Console                    1     87,864 K
chrome.exe                    6824 Console                    1     19,960 K
cmd.exe                      17736 Console                    1      4,004 K
conhost.exe                  11388 Console                    1     18,512 K
tasklist.exe                  1608 Console                    1      8,500 K
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think there is no enough information. Could you post the processes running on your machine?

Comment: Do you mean the 'tasklist' command?

Comment: If it is getting freeze there should be one process with a big processor use, memory consumption growing or an intensive HD use.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego I was not specific enough. Sorry. I mean Hybris freezes, not Windows. Everything else works

Comment: Try a virtual machine with Linux better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to this issue: [Backoffice MediaRemovalException on startup on Windows](https://jira.hybris.com/browse/ECP-3841), which is fixed by [Persistence of backoffice configuration is not thread safe](https://jira.hybris.com/browse/ECP-3259).

Consider updating to a more recent 1808 patch. The latest (as of November 2019) is 1808.18.

Answer (score 1):

I've just cleared all cookies and history, opened backoffice in as a private tab and it resolved my issues.